# snakemake error Command 'set -euo pipefail; Rscript --vanilla meta.R' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: r, snakemake

I am creating a snakemake workflow to download geodatasets. However, I get the following error

```
RuleException: CalledProcessError in file /home/sara/sara/Snakefile, line 8: Command 'set -euo pipefail; Rscript --vanilla /home/sara/sara/.snakemake/scripts/tmps2lv_wlb.meta.R' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
File "/home/sara/sara/Snakefile", line 8, in __rule_download 
File"/home/sara/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run Shutting down, this might take some time. Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Here is my snakemake file

```
configfile: "config.yml"
rule download:
    output: 
        dir= directory("/home/sara/sara/downloads/")
    params:
        sample=config["Samples"]
    script: 
        "scripts/meta.R"
```

Here is my config.yml

```
env:
            - bioconductor-oligo
            - bioconducor-GEOquery
channels:
            - conda-forge
            - bioconda
Samples:
            - "GSE6955"
            - "GSE67311"
```

Here is the Rscript

```
library(GEOquery)
getGEOSuppFiles(snakemakege@params[sample],baseDir = snakemake@output[dir])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Perhaps [Seurat discussion](https://github.com/crazyhottommy/pyflow_seurat_parameter/issues/6) speaks to the above issue? 127 is command not found...

Comment: I solved this and now I have error 'set -euo pipefail;  Rscript --vanilla /home/sara/sara/.snakemake/scripts/tmpd3nox8a_.meta.R' returned **non-zero exit status 1**

Comment: RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file /home/sara/sara/Snakefile, line 8:
Command 'set -euo pipefail;  Rscript --vanilla /home/sara/sara/.snakemake/scripts/tmps2lv_wlb.meta.R' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/home/sara/sara/Snakefile", line 8, in __rule_download
  File "/home/sara/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message

Comment: Well, down to 'it failed', exit code 1, that is still progress.

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect the current status / error message?

Comment: [cross-post](https://www.biostars.org/p/9549467/)